# Intermittent 'this site can't be reached' problem with saving admin settings panel

Tags: magento2, admin

long post, but this is a strange problem.

I'm currently running Magento 2.1.9 community with the porto 2.6.2 theme.

Every time I try and save the 'Stores -> Configuration -> Porto Settings' Panel admin page it's a lottery as to whether the page will save or not. Half the time it's fine, the other half of the time I get 'this site cannot be reached' (with a changed key in browser) and have to go back and try again. Other admin pages are fine.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Some of the time, when it craps out it will also erase part of the information in an unrelated field in that admin page, eg will wipe out part of the 'Previous Link Text' field and save the changes. So it does at least appears to be doing something.

This admin page primarily contains custom css information. I have removed all of this into a custom CSS file to shorten the information on the admin page, but the problem still persists.

I have tried:

- clearing cookies in browser
- different browsers
- different machines
- clearing static files in magento
- ticketing porto, but they say its probably server related

and yet problem persists. I have seen this on 2 different porto magento 2 installs, but not on other themes. The only way I've ever 'solved' this was when I started using a SSL certificate on one site and converted the admin/site to https and the problem magically disappeared.

Changing the other site to https without a certificate didn't solve the problem, and i don't see how this would be related in any case.

Has anyone else had a similar experience in Magento 2 admin?

Many thanks for reading.

Comment: You know much about your server and what environment you have?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have kind of solved this one in case anyone's getting a similar issue.

Switching to https for the admin area DOES seem to work, not more connection drops - even without a valid https certificate.

Still no idea why this would be...

Comment: is this on a live server?